# From coset set G/H to group G

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a [core-free](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Core-free_subgroup) subgroup. Consider the coset set $G/H$.

Assume that we have $G/H$ on which we can do whatever we want, but no more $G$ (and $H$) which is *forgotten* or *hidden*. Can we recover $G$ (and eventually $H$)? How?

By "we can do whatever we want" I mean everything (properties, operations) for which the cosets are considered as *elements* of $G/H$ but *not* as subset of $G$ (otherwise we obviously just need to take the union of all the cosets to recover $G$). For example, we can consider the multiplication of two such elements as a set of elements (exactly as the multiplication of two cosets $gH g'H$ decomposes as a disjoint union of cosets).

Note that the *core-free* assumption is necessary to avoid obvious counter-examples.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by knowing the elements of $G/H$. What do you know about them? If you know how to take a product then you can still take the union to get $G$ and only $H\in G/H$ will form a group.

Comment: Can you work out a small example? Say $G=S_3$ and $H$ a subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain: to compute the decomposition of the product of two cosets you need to consider them as subsets of $G$ and to know the product on $G$. The point is that you can take the computation for granted and write the result only by considering the cosets as elements of $G/H$. As *sets*, for any $gH,g'H \in G/H$ there is $g_1H,\dots, g_rH \in G/H$ such that $$ gHg'H  = \dot\bigcup_i g_iH$$ so as *elements* we can provide the data of that by introducing the following new operation $$  gH \cdot g'H  = \{ g_1H,\dots, g_rH \}. $$ I hope it is a bit clearer.

Comment: $S_3$ is easily recognised, because it is the only possibility, but how would you distinguish $A_n$ from $S_n$ for $n \ge 4$?

Comment: Given much more information (random example: isomorphic subgroup lattices) finite groups are usually not distinguishable, so it is not reasonable to expect that is the case here. Still, I have not understood what the question is. What are the data for $G=S_3$ and $H$ as above?

Comment: @the_fox: if we consider the example of the product of cosets which is just one example of *allowed* operations in the sense explained in the post, for $G=S_3$ and $H=S_2$, $G/H = \{H,aH,bH \}$ with $a=(1,3)$, $b=(1,3,2)$. Then $H \cdot aH = \{ aH \}$,  $aH \cdot bH = \{H, bH \}$, etc...

Comment: My previous interpretation of what you are asking was apparently wrong, and I noe honestly have no idea what you are asking. Rather than giving examples, could you try and give a more formal statement of the question. What does does mean for a coset to be given as an element, for example?

Comment: @DerekHolt: a coset $gH$ is both an element of $G/H$ and a subset of $G$. But because $G$ is *hidden* (the goal being to recover it), it is not allowed to consider $gH$ as a subset of $G$, but just as an element of $G/H$.

Comment: The goal is to prove whether we can collect enough information that can be written using the cosets just considered as elements (as for example the data given by the product of two cosets) to recover $G$.

Comment: @the_fox: it is an open problem whether for every finite group $G$ there exists $n$ such that the subgroup lattice $\mathcal{L}(G^n)$ completely characterize $G$.

Comment: Could you give a list of what information you are given exactly? Otherwise it is impossible to give a satisfying answer. So you have $G/H = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$, a set of some elements, say $x_i = g_iH$. You have the "product" $x_ix_j = S_{i,j}$, where $S_{i,j}$ is some subset of $G/H$. Derek Holt already gave you an example that this information does not determine $G$ nor $H$. What other information do you have?

Comment: @spin: here is an idea inspired by a recent exchange with a colleague: the action of $G$ on $X=G/H$ is transitive so that it admits a unique orbit. But, for $n>1$, the usual action of $G$ on $X^n$ is not transitive, and so induces a non-trivial partition. So an additional information could a partition of $X^n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: Ok, I am not sure if there is a counterexample for information about the action on $X^n$. But I would suggest that you ask a precise question - if the answer does not satisfy you, you can always ask another question with more properties involved. Otherwise it becomes a silly game where somebody finds a counterexample for you, you add more conditions, they find another example, and so on. This kind of exchange is a bit tiring and uninteresting for the people giving answers. A problem is also that the definition of the properties of $G/H$ is not clear.

Comment: I understand a little better now. You basically have an $n$-set $[n]=\{1, \dots, n\}$, where $i$ simply stands for the coset $g_iH$ (assuming you have fixed a transversal). This writing seems suitable to conceal any information about $G$ or $H$. For this $n$-set you can define any operation you want, provided that it comes from a "natural" operation on cosets. For example, you might write $i \ast j =k $ if $g_iH g_jH = g_kH$. The question then is, if we have a machine that can answer any query about operations we ask it, can we recover $G$ and $H$?

Comment: @spin If I have understood correctly the question, the problem is not so much that the question is not specific. Rather, it is difficult to formulate the basic assumption rigorously.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I am sorry that my "allowed data" assumption is not clear enough, but I don't know how to make it clearer. Here is an other allowed data (suggested by a private discussion with a colleague) perhaps it can help to identify the concept: let $X=G/H$ then the usual action of $G$ on $X$ is transitive and so admits a unique orbit; now for $n>1$, the usual action on $X^n$ is no more transitive and so induces a partition. So an allowed data can also be: a partition of $X^n$, for all $n$. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux No, this is not clearer (at least to me). What does this have to do with considering a coset as an element of $G/H$ (rather than as a subset)?

Comment: @verret: It is just that to consider a partition of $X^n$ with $X=G/H$ we don't need to consider the elements of $X$ as subsets of $G$. At the opposite, to consider the union of the element of $X$ we must consider them as subsets. Is it *a bit* clearer?

Answer (score 5):

I checked by computer that if $G=A_4$ with $H=A_3$, then the product of two cosets $(gH)(g'H)$ is the single coset $gH$ when $g'H=H$, and otherwise it is the union of the three cosets that are not equal to $gH$.

The same is true when $G=S_4$ and $H=S_3$ so, if I have understood the question correctly, then the answer is no, it is not possible to recover $H$ and $G$ from this information.

After thinking about it some more (rather than doing computations), any two doubly transitive groups of the same degree with behave in the same way as this example, and so will also provide counterexamples. So, for example, there are two such groups with$|G| = 72$ and $|H|=8$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I made the same computation. Unfortunatly, it does not answer my question, the product of two cosets is just an example of *allowed* operation as I wrote in the post: << For example, we can consider the multiplication of two ... >>. But there could exist others properties or operations on $G/H$ that can be written by considering the cosets as elements and *not* as subsets of $G$, as explained in the post.